# Passing in variables assigned in Shell script

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I am trying to run a Terraform deployment via a Shell script where within the Shell script I first dynamically collect the access key for my Azure storage account and assign it to a variable.  I then want to use the variable in a -var assignment on the terraform command line.  This method works great when configuring the backend for remote state but it is not working for doing a deployment.  The other variables used in the template are being pulled from a terraform.tfvars file.  Below is my Shell script and Terraform template:

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

subscription_name="Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN"
tfstate_storage_resource_group="terraform-state-rg"
tfstate_storage_account="terraformtfstatesa"

az account set --subscription "$subscription_name"
tfstate_storage_access_key=$(
  az storage account keys list \
  --resource-group "$tfstate_storage_resource_group" \
  --account-name "$tfstate_storage_account" \
  --query '[0].value' -o tsv
)

echo $tfstate_storage_access_key

terraform apply \
  -var "access_key=$tfstate_storage_access_key"
```

Deployment template:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "${var.sub_id}"
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "rg" {
  backend = "azurerm"

  config {
    storage_account_name = "terraformtfstatesa"
    container_name       = "terraform-state"
    key                  = "rg.stage.project.terraform.tfstate"
    access_key           = "${var.access_key}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "my_table" {
  name                     = "${var.storage_account}"
  resource_group_name      = "${data.terraform_remote_state.rg.rgname}"
  location                 = "${var.region}"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
```

I have tried defining the variable in my terraform.tfvars file:

```
storage_account = "appastagesa"

les_table_name = "appatable

region = "eastus"

sub_id = "abc12345-099c-1234-1234-998899889988"

access_key = ""
```

The access_key definition appears to get ignored.

I then tried not using a `terraform.tfvars` file, and created the variables.tf file below:

```
variable storage_account {
  description = "Name of the storage account to create"
  default     = "appastagesa"
}

variable les_table_name {
  description = "Name of the App table to create"
  default     = "appatable"
}

variable region {
  description = "The region where resources will be deployed (ex. eastus, eastus2, etc.)"
  default     = "eastus"
}

variable sub_id {
  description = "The ID of the subscription to deploy into"
  default     = "abc12345-099c-1234-1234-998899889988"
}

variable access_key {}
```

I then modified my `deploy.sh` script to use the line below to run my terraform deployment:

```
terraform apply \
  -var "access_key=$tfstate_storage_access_key" \
  -var-file="variables.tf"
```

This results in the error `invalid value "variables.tf" for flag -var-file: multiple map declarations not supported for variables Usage: terraform apply [options] [DIR-OR-PLAN]` being thrown.

Comment: sorry, but what is not working? any errors?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a reduced example but you still need to define the variables you use in `variable "var_name" {}` style.

Comment: @ChandanNayak I am unable to execute the terraform command line where I pass in a variable and use a variables file at the same time.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I forgot about defining the variable as you mentioned but it did not seem to change anything.  I edited the original post to reflect how I tried adding the declaration and the outcomes.

Comment: looks like your access_key is getting the value as a map instead of string, what does your "echo $tfstate_storage_access_key" prints ?

Comment: @ChandanNayak the map error happens whether or not I have the `access_key` variable defined or not.  It is almost like it does not like me using the `-var` and the `-var-file` together.  Not sure what you mean by the echo...it prints the value of the variable (which is the storage access key) to the console.  I added that line just to verify that I was actually grabbing the key.

Answer (score 1):

After playing with this for hours...I am almost embarrassed as to what the problem was but I am also frustrated with Terraform because of the time I wasted on this issue.

I had all of my variables defined in my `variables.tf` file with all but one having default values.  For the one without a default value, I was passing it in as part of the command line.  My command line was where the problem was.  Because of all of the documentation I read, I thought I had to tell terraform what  my variables file was by using the `-var-file` option.  Turns out you don't and when I did it threw the error.  Turns out all I had to do was use the `-var` option for the variable that had no defined default and terraform just automagically saw the `variables.tf` file.  Frustrating.  I am in love with Terraform but the one negative I would give it is that the documentation is lacking.